# Swift 3 error when using didPressRightButton() (SlackTextViewController)

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to implement `didPressRightButton()` from `SlackTextViewController` using the following code and it is giving me an error since migrating to `Swift 3` using `Xcode 8`.

```
override func didPressRightButton(sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let messageToSend = self.textInputbar.textView.text {

        // Save messageToSend to db
        self.textInputbar.textView.text = ""
        super.didPressRightButton(sender)
    }
}
```

The Error that I'm now getting is,

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.

I'm not sure why this appeared since `Swift 3`, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should retype the method, as in new version it has been probably changed. Try to type the method in the IDE and wait for suggestions. Methods differ many times just by underscore character or parameter names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error since upgrading to Swift 3 because **SlackTextViewController** is written in **Objective-C**.

Since Swift 3, the Objective-C type `id` is now imported as `Any` not `AnyObject`.

So when you are calling `super.didPressRightButton(sender)` with a `sender` of type `AnyObject`, Swift compiler can't find the method you are referring to.

> Fix: Just change `AnyObject` to `Any` in your method definition. (Not sure if optionality is needed though…)